# Block Penalty Kicks?

Tags: fifa-13

In Fifa 13, how do you block penalty kicks from the other team in a Penalty Shootout? The game didn't come with an instruction manual so I don't know much about the controls. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! 
EDIT:
I only saved a few goals with the thing called luck.

Comment: I don't know the correct controlls. But when I press both sticks in the direction where I'll jump, then it works. And yes, you'll save them with luck. Like in RL.

Comment: @DarkDecipio Hahaha same thing. I do both sticks as well. Probably only need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Playstation 3 and Xbox 360, you move your goalkeeper along the goal-line with the left stick and as the penalty is taken, you move the right stick in the direction that you wish to dive.